# Do I have to put "that is" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> A watch not worth a penny was being sold there.

In this sentence, do I have to, must and should put "that is" like this?

> A watch that is not worth a penny was being sold there.

Comment: No, but the deletion robs you of a distinction ('A watch that was not worth a penny was being sold there' vs 'A watch that is not worth a penny was being sold there').

Answer (score 3):

> A watch not worth a penny was being sold there.
>
> In this sentence, do I have to, must and should put "that is" like this?
>
> A watch that is not worth a penny was being sold there.

No, you should not. The reason is that you cannot assume the present tense. The watch wasn't worth a penny at the time but you don't know how much it is worth now.

Therefore you can either leave the sentence unchanged, or you can add 'was', as follows:

A watch that *was* not worth a penny was being sold there.

I prefer the original, shorter version.

Answer (score 2):

You may, but it is perfectly idiomatic without it. It is a [small clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_clause).

Comment: Yes. If it's not there, I'll fill it in without even thinking about it; if I happen to be in a mood where I care about such minutiae. The guts of the meaning comes across either way.